# Problems with Bootstrap tables in PHP

Tags: php, apache, twitter-bootstrap

So, I found this cool PHP script on the web called **Listr**. It makes your Index directories much prettier. I also noticed someone made a version specifically for Bootstrap, but opted not to use it (I don't want something over complicated, nor do I want to compile things).

So, I went along with the original Listr, added and removed a couple things to make it mobile friendly, and here is the result:
 [image]
So, for whatever reason, only the first line shows up properly under **Name**. I really don't know why; I've tried several placements of `<table>`, `<th>`, and `<tr>`... none of my methods seem to work.

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/uHSJhFyq (sorry, it's minified! you'll have to unminify it to read it :/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the `<tbody>`:

```
<tbody>
<?if($folder_list):?>
    <?foreach($folder_list as $item):?>
        <tr>
            <th><a href=<?=$item['name']?>/><?=$item['name']?></a></th>
            <th><?=$item['size']['num']?><?=$item['size']['str']?></th>
            <th><?=time_ago($item['mtime'])?> ago</th>
        </tr>
    <?endforeach;?>
<?endif;?>
<?if($file_list):?>
    <?foreach($file_list as $item):?>
        <tr>
            <th><a href=<?=$item['name']?>.<?=$item['ext']?>><?=$item['name']?>.<?=$item['ext']?></a></th>
            <th><?=$item['size']['num']?><?=$item['size']['str']?></th>
            <th><?=time_ago($item['mtime'])?> ago</th>
        </tr>
    <?endforeach;?>
<?endif;?>
</tbody>
```